# AJAX Cart with Drag & Drop Magento extension does not work on home page

Tags: magento

I am new to magento, already tried enough things about this extension, but find nothing. She is functioning normally in the product, but the product list on the home page does not work, please someone could direct me to a possible cause? Already, thank you.

```
<?php
class Devinc_Ajaxcart_Block_Product_List_New extendsMage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
{    

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_productsCount = Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/popup_configuration/product_number'); 
    parent::_construct();
}

public function getAdditionalContentType() {
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/popup_configuration/additional_content');
}

public function getAdditionalContent() {
    return $this->getProductCollection();
}

public function getAcAddToCartUrl($_product) {      
    $params = Mage::helper('ajaxcart')->getUrlParams($this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)); 
    unset($params['uenc']);
    $url = Mage::getUrl('ajaxcart/index/init', $params);

    return "ajaxcart.initAjaxcart('".$url."', this, 'success');";
}

public function getAcAddToWishlistUrl($_product) {        
    $url = str_replace('wishlist/index/add/','ajaxcart/wishlist/add/', $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product));

    if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
        return "javascript:ajaxcart.addToWishlist('".$url."', 'success')";
    } else {
        return "javascript:ajaxcartLogin.loadLoginPopup('".$url."', 'success');";
    }
}

public function getAcAddToCompareUrl($_compareUrl) {        
    $url = str_replace('catalog/product_compare/add', 'ajaxcart/product_compare/add', $_compareUrl);

    return "javascript:ajaxcart.addToCompare('".$url."', 'success')";
}
```

}

Comment: Ziru, you need to share your code, also you need explain where is your problem? after that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to magento, and do not know much about the extension.
But it not only works on the home page. The only thing I know is that it changes the call javascript method setLocation() to ajaxcart.initAjaxcart(), probably using a block, but I can not manually call where I want.